# Unable to change Bootstrap CSS Nav Bar Color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, colors, uinavigationbar

I am using bootstrap CSS Navbar and I cannot change the color of the text inside the NavBar. This is my html code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
       <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a class = "nav_color"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> UserName </a></li>

         <li><a class = "nav_color"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Book </a></li>

         <li><a class = "nav_color"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Pencil </a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

And here is my css code:

```
    .nav_color {
       color: red;
    }
```

I don't understand why this isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AXC**, Hi there.

Try doing it with this.

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: red;
}
```

[image: navbar text color]

Comment: how to close a question?

Comment: Looks like you just did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **!important**.

```
.nav-color {
    color: red !important;
}
```

What is happening is that CSS has specific **precedences** for applying styles. One of the factors is **specificity calculations**. More specific rules (like the one Bootstrap defines) have higher precedence than others more generic (like your class). If you use **!important** you can override the precedence of that rule.

For more information, check [this article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

Comment: Thank you this is really interesting!